# RegEx, Exclude All Whitespace Except Space

Tags: regex

I have a simple RegEx that is being used to match all Non-Whitespace Characters

```
([^\s])
```

Which is fine but the only issue is that it is not matching on valid Whitespace (valid in my case) which is just a regular space

How can I add an exception to this exclusion for regular space? Match all Non-Whitespace Characters but also match for Space

Comment: `[^\s]` => `[^\s ]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I might be wrong but this comment looks to be chaining Space with the \s argument which includes Space anyway

Comment: Then you need `[^\S ]`. `\s` matches more than `\t`, `\n` and `\r` and space.

Comment: If I reversed it to be *[\S ]* then it works, I didn't know about the *\S* arg but it seems to match everything that isn't a space, then chain the space to that

Comment: I want to match the spaces though, \S matches everything that is not whitespace. So [\S] to match all now-whitespace then also include regular space with [\S ]

Comment: That is right then. `\S` + space => `[\S ]`

Comment: Off topic but how do you format the code like that in the comments?

Comment: Use backticks. When you have backticks, use double backticks.

Comment: Testing `CODE LINE`

Comment: Oh wow, that's nice, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the regex - `[^\t\n\r\f\v]`

i.e manually exclude all the whitespace *except* for space.

Check out the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gGBbw3/2)

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, `\s` contains more than just `\t\n\r`. Although `\t\n\r` *are* the common ones, it's not the end of the story, far from it! I've added those into the regex as well.

However, thanks to [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), the preferred, and easier, answer should be- `[\S ]`

This will include *only* **non-whitespace** characters *and* space.

Check out the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2ZOt8K/1)

Comment: Wow I feel stupid, I never knew you could specify tabs, newlines and returns like that. This is exactly what I need thank you so much!

Comment: I have to wait a while before accepting this as the answer but this solved my problem

Comment: This answer solved my issue but it'd be great if you updated the answer to also include the *[\S ]* method as well, I think it can help other users

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it should be `[\S ]` right?

Comment: @TheLovelySausage Updated my answer